# How to periodically synchronize NTP time with local timer-based time

Tags: time, arduino, clock, esp8266, ntp

I have an embedded system with WiFi (based on an 80MHz ESP8266, developed using Arduino IDE), and I would like it to keep reasonably accurate clock time (to one second), using the two tools at its disposal: the internet, and its own internal timers.

Challenges:

- The processor clock will likely drift over time, ostensibly in a
  predictable manner.
- NTP uses UDP, so return packets with the time are not guaranteed to
  return in order, or to return within any set interval, or to return
  at all.
- Latency of return NTP packets varies widely over time, from under
  100ms to (potentially) several seconds.
- Latency of DNS varies widely over time, from under 100ms up to
  several seconds (I can't control the timeout). DNS is needed to look
  up IP addresses for the NTP server pool(s).
- The system takes various actions based on certain times and
  intervals, so I don't want to over-control the time, setting it
  forward and backward continually, causing actions to be needlessly
  missed or duplicated (or, alternatively, to complicate the program
  logic handling all of these conditions - an occasional miss or
  duplicate is not mission critical).
- Sometimes an NTP server will return the wrong time (e.g.,
  pool.ntp.org occasionally returns 0 seconds since 1900, which is easy
  to detect)
- Sometimes a stray return packet with an old time will arrive just
  ahead of the return packet from the current request.

Current Approach:

- Keep a local device time incrementing using an ISR triggered every 0.1
  second.
- Periodically poll (currently every 6 minutes, but really doesn't have
  to be this often) an NTP server (pool).
- Try again if there's no response within a short interval (currently 1
  second, which is shorter than typical but most requests return in
  under 150ms).
- Vary the NTP server (pool) on each try, to spread the load and to
  average out response times and any service errors.
- Extract the time to the nearest 0.1 second (and adjust for typical
  receive latency).
- If the NTP time is off from the local device time by more than a
  second, update the local device time (in a critical section).
- Timeout, retry, and re-initialize (where appropriate), for failed
  network elements of the process. Abandon the request after most hope
  is lost, and just try again next time.

Is there a better, or canonical, or best practices way to do this time synchronization? Are there other factors or approaches I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

For automatic updating time from the internet or GPS system will overkill a cheap arduino project, for you may require a Ethernet shield and write a TSR program that will regularly send updated time to the arduino. Instead you can purchase more accurate RTC clock ( some are getting more accurate these days) and manually update the clock from time to time using keyboard and LED display incorporated with the arduino. If at all your project is very time critical, it is better to you some cheap crystal based solution instead.

Comment: I considered an RTC of course, but I have many of these devices and this is not a commercial project, so I want to minimize unit cost. I can get an ESP8266 (with WiFi) for a fraction of just about any other processor with included or external internet capability. These are embedded data collection devices, so once deployed, it's very inconvenient to extract them and do anything manual. I think most of the same design constraints apply to any system trying to synchronize from two different time sources though.